# How to use BinaryWriter to write double value?

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, binarywriter

I have two applications that needs to pass value to each other in a fast way, and some value needs to be kept(when I restart my computer it still exist), so I need to create a file, now I know how to do with `int`:

```
    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(@"C:\TEST", FileMode.Open)))
    {
        writer.Write(0);  //00 00 00 00
        writer.Write(1);  //01 00 00 00
        writer.Write(2);  //02 00 00 00
        writer.Write(3);  //03 00 00 00 
        writer.Write(int.MaxValue); //FF FF FF 7F
    }

    byte[] test = new byte[4];
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(@"C:\TEST", FileMode.Open)))
    {

        reader.BaseStream.Seek(8, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        reader.Read(test, 0, 4);
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToInt32(test, 0));     //2

        reader.BaseStream.Seek(16, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        reader.Read(test, 0, 4);
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToInt32(test, 0));     //2147483647    

        Console.Read();
    }
```

But how to do with `double`?

Comment: You could answer this question yourself simply by reading the relevant documentation. Any question that can be answered that way should not be asked here in the first place because you should ALWAYS have read the relevant documentation before posting a question here.

Comment: Also, the way you're reading the data makes no sense. You're creating a `BinaryReader` and not even using it. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its as easy as

```
writer.Write((double)int.MaxValue);
```

[BinaryWriter Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx)

> [Write(Double)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez8wcba9(v=vs.110).aspx)  Writes an eight-byte floating-point value to the
>   current stream and advances the stream position by eight bytes

As for reading

```
reader.ReadDouble()
```

[BinaryReader.ReadDouble Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readdouble(v=vs.110).aspx)